# Power series solutions for a system of algebraically dependent polynomial equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

We have  a set of algebraically dependent polynomials with a common zero.  Can we still expect an implicit function theorem type statement for this system around its common zero ? By this i mean, can we hope to approximate some of the variables by power series (not necessarily unique) in the remaining variables in the neighborhood of this solution ?

Or, is there an easy counterexample to this ?

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: I meant - if the polynomials are algebraically independent and have a common zero where the Jacobian is non-singular, then this is just the standard implicit function theorem.